# Список всех грантов таблиц oracle

Tags: oracle

Всем доброго дня.

Есть ли в oracle какая-нибудь таблица, хранящая в себе все гранты таблиц?
Или как можно получить список всех грантов таблиц? Например, грантов на select для схемы abc?

Answer (score 0):

Например, список всех грантов, выданных на SELECT таблиц схемы ABC

```
select * from ALL_TAB_PRIVS where privilege = 'SELECT' and table_schema = 'ABC'
```